# Cancel UIAnimation without removing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an animation block that moves a `UIImageView` from the top of the screen to the bottom. If the user taps the screen at any point during the animation, I want the `UIImageView` to stop in it's place.

Currently, I have

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^(void){
   [self.myImage setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height-20)];
}];

[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

But `removeAllAnimations` doesn't stop my UIImageView from animating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a new animation with 0.0 duration will cancel the previous and start the new one. That might as well do nothing and keep your `UIImageView` at the point the user stopped it:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{redView.frame = ((CALayer *)redView.layer.presentationLayer).frame;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [CATransaction begin];
                     [redView.layer removeAllAnimations];
                     [CATransaction commit];
                 }];
```

BeginFromCurrent state lets you take the image at any place.

Comment: I don't understand. Where does this block indicate the final location of the imageview?

Comment: There you go, missed the completion code. Sorry about that. Just tested works like a charm. Of course this is the code you should execute when the user taps to stop the animation.